# Accessing user defined properties using spring expression language

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is it poosible to read user defined `.properties` file using SpEL? I know we can  do something like this for systemProperties

```
  @Value("#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }")
```

I want to access a property in a user defined properties file. Also is it possible to use SpEL in `@ContextConfiguration` annotation? I want to set the value of this annotation using a properties file defined by me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do:

```
private @Value("${propertyName}") String propertyField;
```

And you will need `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:myProps.properties" />
```

or with java config

```
@PropertySource("classpath:myProps.properties")
```

on the config class

Comment: I want to be able to set the value of ContextConfiguration annotation based on a property file. Your solution doesn't seem to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use...

```
@Bean
public Properties props() {
    ...
}

@Value("#{props.foo}")
```

How do you want to use SpEL in `@ContextConfiguration` ?